# read a line from a file and split the line in perl

Tags: perl

I have to read a specific line (line contains `is successfully created.`) from a text file and have to split the line and store the specific values in variables.

The full line is

```
LOG----Payrun.c:0263:28/11/16 07:45:04 > Pay file /home/user/dev/MODULE447/input/all/20161111/PAY001.TXT is successfully created.
```

I have to get the string value `/home/user/dev/MODULE447/input/all/20161111/` into one variable and `PAY001.TXT` into another variable.

Can any body help me with reading from the file and getting the required values into variables?

Comment: Try it by your own and come back if you have a specific problem. SO is not "a write code for me" service

Comment: Actually i am new to perl and not aware of file processing. Mean while i am trying to do it by my own with the help of google. Any how thanks for your response.

Comment: You're supposed to do the research *before* asking the question, not while you wait for answers.

Comment: Better you can vote for answers

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will do it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

#iterate stdin or files specified on command line. 
while ( <> ) {
   #regex match, capturing part of the match. 
   #note - non whitespace matching, so will break if you've whitespace chars in your filenames 
   #or paths. 
   if ( my ( $path, $file ) = m,\s(\S+/)(\S+) is successfully created, ) {
      print "Path = $path, file = $file","\n";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have started this for you:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $inputfile = $ARGV[0];
my $matchedline = "";

#open file
open(INPUT, $inputfile) || die "Can't reason $!\n";
while(<INPUT>) #Each line looping
{  $matchedline .= $_ if($_=~m/is successfully created/g);  } #Check matched line

print $matchedline; #Confirm the matched line.
```

> After this you will try to store in the new file and this is for your assignment